# jQuery each function only returning last result of total results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with key : value pair. I'm looping through this object and if the key matches the value that's passed into my function I add it to another variable. The problem is that my code ends up looping through the results and only adding the last match to my new variable.

```
function DirectoryOfBusinessSubs(parentID) {
     var myOpt = {"1":"<option>sub1</option>","1":"<option>sub2</option>"};
     var myList;
     $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
                    if(key == parentID){
                    myList += value;
                    }
                });
                alert(myList);
                c.append(myList);
        }
```

If I am passing in `1` for the key, `myList` should get both sub1 and sub2, but this code is only storing sub2 in `myList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function DirectoryOfBusinessSubs(parentID) {
     var myOpt = {"<option>sub1</option>":"1","<option>sub2</option>":"1"};
     var myList = ''; //Fix undefined alert
     $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
                    if(value== parentID){
                    myList += key;
                    }
                });
                alert(myList);
                c.append(myList);
        }
```

THIS MUST DO THE WORK :)

Comment: I will if you become registered.

Comment: I log with my google account, how to register ? I have profile here user:66776 ?!?

Answer (score 0):

include another scope:

```
$.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
                    (function(v){
                      if(key == parentID){
                        myList += v;
                      }
                    })(value);
                });
                alert(myList);
                c.append(myList);
        }
```

[`JavaScript closures`](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62)